# How can I serve vendor js file from a node package via meteor server

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, web-worker

I have to pass a javascript library available in a npm package to a `Worker`. Now worker can only import via `importScripts`. So, how do I do it other than keeping the whole minified js in public directory?